# gcloud functions deploy not uploading html and css

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I created following express API

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
require("dotenv/config");
//routes
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth.js");
const adminRoute = require("./routes/admin.js");
//middleweres
//converting body into json using body parser
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/", express.static("public"));
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/admin", adminRoute);

// starting express server
// app.listen(5000, () => {
//   console.log("listning on port 5000");
// });

module.exports = {
  app,
};
```

in public folder I have html file and css and js inside public/static folders
html, css and js in public folder are generated with react build.
I am trying to deploy this API in google cloud function with following command

```
gcloud functions deploy outreach-dashboard --entry-point app --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

function is getting deployed but problem is when I see the function on gcp dashboard it source does not contain public folder and if I download source as zip then I can see public folder there but its empty.
I need public folder to get deployed so I can serve it using

```
express.static("public")
```

Comment: Do the no static routes work?

Comment: No they did not
I also find that by removing /public from my .gitignore file they started to pop up in GCF.
but still GCF is not serving static html,css and giving me 403 error
but I think that is completely different question

Comment: So now, you have a 403 and not a 404? Correct? Do you still use the --allow-unauthenticated parameter?

Comment: Yes I am still using --allow-unauthenticated
I feel I should host static file somewhere else and only use cloud function to host API

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have deployed new files to `public` folder and they are not deployed. I tried this  on new `helloworld` deployment and its working fine. I can add and remove files and directories each deployment, there must be somthing wrong with your account... I think you should reach support or try new project

Comment: I can add new files perfectly 
problem is I can not access static Images or html file from cloud function 
I am deploying app function which is an express object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I have remove public folder from `.gitignore`
and after that also need to tell GCF to treat public folder as static folder by creating `app.yaml` file in root folder

content of app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs12

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: public

  - url: /.*
    script: auto
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to serve several endpoints in the same Cloud Functions. I saw some hack on Stack overflow where folks bend the framework to achieve this. It's not my recommendation.

[Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) is a very similar platform. The same underlying infrastructure, and feature very close (I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-cloud-functions-whats-the-lowest-cost-728d59345a2e)). But you serve a containerize webserver, more suitable for your use case.

You can easily have a try on it.

- Uncomment your "starting app express" part
- Test locally if it works.

Then run this command

```
gcloud beta run deploy outreach-dashboard --source=. --platform=managed --region=us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated
```

*change the region if needed*

The command :

- upload the sources (take care of your `.gitignore` and `.gcloudignore` file to be sure to upload all the files)
- Create a container with your source. To achieve this, [Buildpacks.io](https://buildpacks.io/) is used. Exactly the same process that with Cloud Functions and App Engine.
- Deploy the container on Cloud Run.

If the problem persist, there is may an issue with the automatic container build process (maybe some file are automatically discarded). In this case, you can write a very simple `Dockerfile` similar to this one that you have in the [getting started documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#containerizing).

This time, you can create and deploy in 2 steps (and 2 commands)

```
# create the container with Cloud Build based on the docker file
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/<containerName>

# Deploy on Cloud Run
gcloud beta run deploy outreach-dashboard --image=gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/<containerName> --platform=managed --region=us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated
```